# Which is the best way to append single quotes for a String in java

Tags: java, string, append, string-formatting

For example,

```
String x= "ABC";
```

*Which is the best way to convert ABC to 'ABC' ?*

Comment: `x= "'" + x + "'";`. Better yet, `String x = "'ABC'";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String` inner `StringBuilder` like

```
sb.append(String.format("'%s'", variable));
```

Answer (score 6):

This will create less intermediate `String` objects than with `+`

```
public static String quote(String s) {
    return new StringBuilder()
        .append('\'')
        .append(s)
        .append('\'')
        .toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "ABC";
    String quotedX = quote(x);
    System.out.println(quotedX);
}
```

prints `'ABC'`

Comment: For simple concatenations like this (all on a single line), [the Java compiler will optimise `+` into a `StringBuilder` as needed](http://www.code-thrill.com/2012/08/stringbuilder-optimizations-demystified.html).

Comment: but in this, it is getting an error ```“A1's constructor "```

Answer (score 2):

The other option is the escape character, which in Java is the backslash ().
So: `String x = "\'ABC\'";`

Here is a good [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 2):

For those who uses Spring Framework:

```
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
String x = "ABC";
x = StringUtils.quote(x);
```

> Quote the given String with single quotes. 
> Parameters:
>
> str - the input String (e.g. "myString")
>
> Returns:
>
> the quoted String (e.g. "'myString'"), or null if the input was null

Consider also `StringUtils.quoteIfString(Object obj)`.